# How do you calculate the odds of victory?

Tags: game-of-thrones-ascent

In Game of Thrones Ascent, how do you calculate the odds of victory? If the enemy is defending with a score of 100 and you are attacking with a score of 150, how likely is i that you are going to win? The descriptions presented in the game of Moderate, Challenging, etc aren't as descriptive as I would like.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The chance of winning is a percentage chance equal to Attacker's Attack Rating / (Attacker + Defender Ratings).  So in your example the chance of winning is 150/(100+150) = 150/250 = 60%.  In addition to that, there's always a minimum chance of 5% to win, and a maximum chance of 95% to win.